# Swift 4: What is a way to change the name of a folder on firebase storage, for every save?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am working on an app where a user saves images to firebase. I save the images in a folder and which is inside of another folder. Every time a user pressed a button it send the array of images into the folder. But then i want it to be pressed again and send a new array in another folder. I was able to make this code work by counting the number of images in the array (this would always be different and so it would work) However this is unscalable.

Bellow is the line:

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)!).child("\(PhotoArray.sharedInstance.photosArray.count) Post").child("\(imageName)")
```

What is a more effective and scalable way to do this? I have tried other things like adding 1 to a variable called **numberSaves** But that would not work unless I also make it a variable in the database. Also I hav tried doing `Date().timeIntervalSince1970` But this does not work as intended.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `But this does not work as intended.`: What does not work as intended here with `Date()`? It fills the uniqueness criteria after all. Too much a hassle to query the parent folder for what image-folders are there, or the format not good enough for parsing?

Comment: No, but when I use it it creates a new folder for each image. Wich is equal to the same time interval as I use a for loop to send each image in the array. Here is the imageName var if you want.  let imageName = "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).jpg"

Answer (score 0):

You can make the folderName a variable and reuse it for all images inside the for-loop.

```
let parentFolder = Storage.storage().reference().child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)!)
let imageFolderName = “\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)-Post“
```

And then upload as usual.

```
for image in images {
    let imageName = “\(UUID().uuidString).jpg“
    let storageRef = parentFolder.child(imageFolderName).child(imageName)
    // Upload to storageRef.
}
```

Instead of an `index` or `Date().timeIntervalSince1970` you can also use [`UUID().uuidString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/uuid/1779712-uuidstring), which is the default goto for unique identifiers if order is not an issue.

> I took 2 pictures and it made 2 seperate folders for each image. I want it to be able to take X number images then send to DB and then be able to take more pics and then save and this time have a seperate folder containing the new images. (dosent matter if some of teh old images from teh array are still posted in teh folder)

Do you want to send them to DB every time you press a button or do you upload them continously?

If you do upload continously and only want to switch on button press then only change the `imageFolderName` there, and use `UUID().uuidString` for the `imageName` so images are not overridden.

Comment: I did as you said but. it does not work. I took 2 pictures and it made 2 seperate folders for each image. I want it to be able to take X number images then send to DB and then be able to take more pics and then save and this time have a seperate folder containing the new images. (dosent matter if some of teh old images from teh array are still posted in teh folder)

Comment: Do you want to send them to DB every time you press a button or do you upload them continously? I want them to be sent when you press a button. Not continuesly

Comment: @J.Hoe Does the foldername `imageFolderName` change between each image? Maybe look into it.

Comment: no, but it has the same value as imageName only that they have a diferent ending. IE: jpg or Post

Comment: In what two seperate folders are the two images stored, if the `imageFolderName` did not change? Is there a chance that it came from an earlier invocation? You can try to use a different `imageName` like above `UUID().uuidString` to see whether one just overwrite the second, since `Date().timeIntervalSince1970` only changes [every other second](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timeinterval). Maybe I‘m wrong on the last part though.

Comment: Well I want the new folder to be created inside teh user folder. So it shoudl look like this: UserJhon->ImageFolder1->(Image1,Image2, Image3), ImageFolder2->(Image1,Image2, Image3)

Comment: @J.Hoe I can‘t say more without seeing your current code, until now I was only able to guess.